# How to install a right version phpmyadmin on Centos 6.9 accordingly?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, magento, phpmyadmin

I am moving a Magento 1.8 web to a lower cost hosting and exhausted by phpmyadmin installation.
Magento 1.8 was suggested to run with PHP 5.4 and Mysql 5.5, therefore, I chose a Centos6.9 image and thought could be easier...The LAMP stack installation is smooth, but always got problem with phpmyadmin. I have tried PHP5.4 + Mysql5.5, PHP5.4 + Mysql5.6, PHP5.5 + Mysql5.6 combinations, none of them turn out success...
Most of online blogs suggest same way to install phpmyadmin which I followed as below:

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    or 
    rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    then
    yum install phpmyadmin
```

I thought the EPEL package will be able to automatically identify php modules already installed and install the right version phpmyadmin accordingly...
instead it seems stick with php 5.3 which is default php version with Centos 6....here is error message:

[image: error message]

the list is very long and involved many php modules...

I am kind of newbie with linux server stuff...Can anyone help to address this issue and point a solution out?  thank you in advance.

BTW, I am big fan of open source, but from this point, I feel a bit disappointed to open source products...especially when end user need to work with multiple of them together...it can never be said as user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Remi repo installed you should be able to use:

```
yum install phpmyadmin --enablerepo=remi-php56
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **php 5.4.45** installed from remi-php54, so you need to enabled this repository to install any additional module.

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Please note than PHP 5.4 and 5.5 are not maintained anymore, so I hearthly recommend to upgrade to a supported release (5.6 or more recent)

P.S. phpMyAdmin in EPEL is quite old (4.0) but suitable for old PHP versions. For more recent version of PHP (5.6, 7 and up), you probably need the latest phpMyAdmin version 4.7 (which is available in "remi" reposotiry)

Comment: Thank you for reply. would you please to elaborate how to install phpmyadmin 4.7 on Centos 6....I notice that both Remi and epel has 4.0.10 version for Centos 6 after command: rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm. I check it by command: yum list phpM*.   I have no other idea about how to install 4.7 by using yum.

Comment: It is in the "remi" repository which is not enabled by default (as it overrides lot of base packages)
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin

Comment: I have tried that with php 5.5 installed, but having similar problem...see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439653/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-6-8-with-php-5-5

Comment: You need at least PHP 5.6 (PHP 5.5 is EOL)