# How to install phpMyadmin on Centos 6.8 with php 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I have several headaches on installing phpMyAdmin on Centos 6.8
I have php 5.5 installed from webtatic repo. Mysql 5.6 installed as well.
When I install phpMyAdmin by

```
# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install phpMyAdmin
```

I got these errors:

[image]

[image]

In fact, I had another trial before, I had php 5.4 installed from Remi repo and facing similar problem when installing phpmyadmin, see another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746230/how-to-install-a-right-version-phpmyadmin-on-centos-6-9-accordingly)

I am relatively new to Linux server stuff. I have several questions and hopefully someone could help me out.

1. At this point, what the yum has done? it leave me big hole which I don't know how to proceed from here. it seems yum has removed some my php5.5 modules without getting replacement installed. those php module being removed are needed by my Magento site. And I don't know if phpmyadmin has been installed or not.
2. I don't know what/who cause the problem, or is it because my php was installed from webtatic repo, so I can NOT use Remi repo to install any package that related to php such as phpmyadmin? if so, why yum has no process to prevent the problem?  if it is not, why yum or Remi repo leave such situation to user like this is not their business?  Anyway, in my another try, both php5.4 and phpmyadmin are installed from Remi repo...
3. From phpMyAdmin web, I know that its 4.7 version can work with php 5.5 or later + Mysql 5.5 or later. However, I find only version 4.0 available for Centos 6 in Remi repo by command:
   yum list phpMy*
   My current installation is php 5.5.38 + Mysql 5.6.  Can I install phpmyadmin 4.7 and how (under Centos 6.8)?   I proceeded with installation even I found only 4.0 available as I attempted to upgrade to 4.7 after installation.

First of all, How can I save my installation (including php and mysql) and get phpmyadmin (better to be 4.7) installed properly from here. so I don't have to rebuild the system....Honestly, even rebuild the system again, I still have no idea about the right way to get right phpmyadmin installed without error.

Note: I have to stick with php either 5.4 or 5.5 as my Magento site is 1.8

Any help and explanation will be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance.

Supplement: Ok, by googling, the 3rd question seems found its answer from [here](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-using-yum/). 
It seems I was installing phpMyAdmin 4.7....But why the error since php 5.5 is officially supported by phpMyAdmin 4.7?   is the webtatic repo or the Remi repo too bad? leaving such dependency hole... How to address such issue from here?

Comment: 2017 you still use phpmyadmin?

Comment: Maybe you are going to need to remove those packages and install them again...see this Q&A https://superuser.com/questions/547280/how-to-completely-uninstall-a-package-including-all-extra-files-that-came-with

Comment: @Hackeman  Thank you for reply.  When you said those and them, do you mean all those php, mysql, phpmyadmin packages?  that will be same as rebuilding the whole system which I am trying to avoid....is that the only way out?

Comment: By the way, even to rebuild the whole system, I will still have the same problem when installing phpmyadmin if I have no idea what is right way to install it.....Basically, I hope the three questions could be answered, so I can have some idea about what and where went wrong with whole process...only upon that it is meaningful to do rebuilding as I have rebuilt the system too many times already without success.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried this?

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-a-centos-6-4-vps)

Comment: thank you for reply....But I don't see any difference from the epel repo I installed..the error message already show that this phpmyadmin does not work with php 5.5 module....if it is for trying, I have tried too many times like fool ...I hope someone could answer those three questions before I give further trying....